# How can I use gcm and node.js?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a chat website.I am using node.js for chat in site.I want to build an android app for this site.But there is a problem: How can i use nodejs and gcm together in my app ? I have to use gcm for push notifications and I have to use nodejs library for real time chatting in app. How can I do this ? I don't want any code,just need an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this client xmpp https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp
and may be this https://github.com/jacobp100/node-gcm-ccs